# Can we use Composer with sparse SVN checkout to share dependencies?

Tags: php, svn, composer-php

Our current development setup uses a single Subversion repository containing multiple projects, each with branches, tags, and trunk. We then use a "sparse checkout" to select the projects, and branches of those projects, to work with.

The result is that the directory structure of a working copy matches that of the repository, including branch information, and we never use `svn switch`. (This style of working will probably be familiar to anyone who uses SVN, but may be surprising to those who don't.)

We are thinking of using Composer to manage both external and internal dependencies, but I'm not sure how this can work with the sparse checkout style of working.

I would like some way of using a directory within the existing checkout to satisfy a dependency, rather than each "root project" needing a separate copy.

For example:

- sites/Foo/trunk

  - depends on lib Aaa, so references lib/Aaa/trunk
  - depends on lib Bbb 1.5.*, so references lib/Bbb/branches/release-1.5
- sites/Bar/trunk

  - depends on lib Aaa 1.0.*, so references lib/Aaa/branches/release-1.0
  - depends on lib Bbb 1.5.*, so references lib/Bbb/branches/release-1.5

At present, if I edit the code in lib/Bbb/branches/release-1.5, I can test those changes on both sites, without needing to commit one and update the other.

Is there any way of using Composer to manage these dependencies?

(PS: Please don't answer with "give up on SVN, use Git, it is teh awesomez"; that is an answer to a different question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - I do not believe that you can do this with Composer as standard: it expects to copy the files from whichever source (Packagist/VCS/Zips) to the local vendor folder, which is not what you want.

That said, I believe there are two potential ways you could get this working (at least in part):

### Autoloader

You could try using the `autoload` field in the composer.json file to include the correct files into the project. You would still need to manage the checkouts of the relevant branches/versions manually (like I assume you do now), but you would be able to manage the inclusion of the internal libraries through Composer. This will probably require that your libraries are properly namespaced. The paths to the files for each namespace are relative to the root of the project, but can go below the root (via the `/../` path) if required.

To be honest though, if you already have an autoloader for these files, there may not be much advantage to this solution. [Relevant Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

### Composer Plugin

You could also write a composer plugin/"custom installer" that could probably manage this. This would have the advantage that you could have it manage checking out the correct parts of the sparse repository to have the correct version available, as well as doing correct wildstar version checking, but would be a much more difficult and riskier venture.

The basic process would be that you would define a new package type (e.g. 'internal-svn-package'). You would create the plugin as an external library that gets installed normally via Composer, which declares (via it's composer.json) that it handles this new type of package. Your custom logic would then be used for any packages that are listed with this custom type. I'm not sure how much of the internal composer logic for SVN checkouts you would be able to reuse however. [Relevant Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md)